# Using a custom truststore and keystore in Spring Webclient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to set a custom truststore and a custom keystore in Spring Webclient. This is needed to communicate with a backend server that uses a self signed certificate for https.
I followed several guides to do this but was unable to get a connection. We are using p12 files as keystore and truststore and this worked fine in the old implementation with Spring WebServiceTemplate.
My bean configuration looks like this:

```java
@Bean
public SsiClient ssiClient(
    final ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector,
    final String url,
    final String urlAlternative
)
{
    final WebClient.Builder wcBuilder = WebClient.builder();

    return new SsiClient(wcBuilder
                             .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
                             .baseUrl(url)
                             .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
                                 httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.toString());
                                 httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);
                             })
                             .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> {
                                 clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Encoder(new Jaxb2XmlEncoder());
                                 clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jaxb2Decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder());
                             })
                             .build(), url, urlAlternative);
}

@Bean
public ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector(
    final SslContext sslContext
)
{
    return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
        HttpClient.create()
                  .secure(
                      sslSpec -> {
                          sslSpec.sslContext(sslContext);
                      }
                  )
    );
}

@Bean
public SslContext sslContext(
    final String keyStorePath,
    final String keyStorePassword,
    final String keyStoreType,
    final String trustStorePath,
    final String trustStorePassword,
    final String trustStoreType
)
{
    try (
        final FileInputStream keyStoreFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStorePath));
        final FileInputStream trustStoreFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(trustStorePath))
    )
    {
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(keyStoreFileInputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        trustStore.load(trustStoreFileInputStream, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = InsecureTrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        return SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                                .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
                                .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
                                .build();

    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        log.error("An error has occurred: ", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But this ends in an error with the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:623)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:464)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runAllDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1550)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1564)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1448)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1275)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1322)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

I am almost certain that this is a configuration error but I cannot find the cause.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this? I am having a similar problem

Comment: I figured out my issues, but it probably wouldnt be helpful for you. For completeness though, I wasn't sending the secured HttpClient by accident, and also I was using OAuth and needed to do extra configuration to make sure my OAuth was using the correct truststore. It looks like you arent using OAuth and are sending the secured HttpClient to the ReactorConnector though.

Comment: Hey Will, glad you could fix your issues. I did not make any headway. I switched everything to the `WebServiceTemplate` provided by `spring-ws`. That is actually want I wanted to avoid but in the end I found no other option.

Comment: Just to be sure, but you never hit your error log when creating the SslContext, correct? When you inspect the ReactorClientHttpConnector when its created, you can see the correct certificates inside its SslContext trustmanager?

Comment: As far as I can remember everything started correctly but the connection could not be established. Then again, it was two months ago, so I am not really sure.